# variable number of submit button

Tags: php, button, submit

Is there a way to distinguish the clicked submit button from the other so I can insert the info chosen in the db?

```
<?php while($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['username'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['firstname'];?>/<?php echo $donnees['lastname'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['email'];?></td>
    <td width="75px"><?php echo $donnees['city'];?></td>
    <td><?php if($donnees['Role']==1) {echo "Student";}
              if($donnees['Role']==2) {echo "Teacher";}?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="<?php echo $donnees['id'];?>></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you need to choose both the value and name different and start with a prefix and end with unique_number, **But this is not a good way**.

Comment: And what is the purpose of the variable number of buttons???

Comment: Every time  a new user signup for the site he needs to be added manually.

Comment: Where you give the facility to add the info from the user for signup?

Comment: that's a diffrent form !!

Comment: this one is a table that shows all the user wanting to join the site.

Comment: so the signup process complete but the users are not granted, here you just confirm a user for completing the signup.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<button>` with `type="submit"` instead. That way you can separate the `value` attribute from what is displayed, and so you can use the `value` to distinguish which submit button was pressed in the request. There's an example of this **[on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp)**.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $donnees['id'];?>">Confirm</button>
```

Then in your PHP, you can use `$_POST["submit"]` to find the `id` of the button that was clicked.

Comment: Thank you i made the change and it works fine.(you just made my day)

Comment: You're welcome! If your question is answered, feel free to click the check mark next to the answer that solved your question. This will let others know that the answer has been found, and that it is what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion i understand that you need to accept / grand a user from this panel, so for this you have already information in your database from where you display into this panel, you can do one thing here.

Make a link from where you will accept/ grand a user for completing signup.

Instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="<?php echo $donnees['id'];?>>
```

Do

```
<a href="confirm.php?id="<?php echo $donnees['id'];?>">Confirm</a>
```

This will go to a new page with the fetch id which is a unique value, you can do the UPDATE statement there and make a user free to login.

> In your `confirm.php` page you need to get the value of id using a
>   `$_GET` method, And make a UPDATE query to update the database table
>   with a valid status for the user.